# Is there any way to return the solution time in ampl?

Tags: ampl

In the default setting, AMPL will not return the solution time. Is there any way to get that information?( (I am using shell)

Answer (score 0):

https://ampl.com/faqs/where-do-i-find-the-amount-of-computation-cpu-time-taken-by-ampl-or-by-a-solver/

> AMPL provides the following built-in timing parameters such as _ampl_time and _total_solve_time. You’ll find the complete list in Table A-14 in the reference appendix of the AMPL book. These timing parameters can be used in all the same ways as ordinary AMPL parameters defined through param statements. Thus in particular you can show their values (or the values of expressions involving them) by use of display or printf commands.